# Java Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and how to trim whitespaces/tabs in properties file

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

I have a property file which is managed in classic way by PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer :

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
    <property name="location" value="classpath:mail.properties" /> 
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="jobDataPathUtils"    class="com.hello.test.DataPathUtils">
    <property name="host" value="${smtp.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${smtp.port}" />
    <property name="username" value="${smtp.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${smtp.pass}" />
</bean>
```

The problem that i have a lots of *String* properties in .properties file, around 30 entries, and if someone adds a tabulation at the end of property value, the application fails to use correctly these properties. I would like to trim each property value before using it. I can do it manually using .trim() on each property in the DataPathUtils class, but i am wondering if there are any other ways to do this, either by PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer either ...?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: I don't know if it's possible but are you sure you wanna do this? Are you sure that all the entries must be trimmed? Some providers allows spaces  in user and password. I think that trim inside DataPathUtils is better idea.

Comment: what do you mean by tabulation ? can you give an example

Comment: @Mudassar, it is a tab character, when you tap on Tab key on your keyboard, you get it

Comment: Marco A. Hernandez, yes i agree in some cases it is not useful to remove whitespaces , but in my case I would like to check that at least there is no  tab character at the end of my property value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think the way your data is entered which has trailing spaces needs to be addressed.
- If the source cannot be controlled then you would need to extend PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and trim it processProperties().
  Using this approach you can change things in future as per requirement like getting data from database or changing a particular key value pair or caching.

  ```
          public class CustomPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {
            /**  
          * Map that hold all the properties.
               */
          private Map<String, String> propertiesMap; 
          /**
           * Iterate through all the Propery keys and build a Map, resolve all the nested values before beuilding the map.
           */
          @Override
          protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, Properties props) throws BeansException {
              super.processProperties(beanFactory, props);

              propertiesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
              for (Object key : props.keySet()) {
                  String keyStr = key.toString();
                  String valueStr = prop.getProperty(keyStr);
                  propertiesMap.put(keyStr.trim(), valueStr.trim());
              }
          } 


          public String getProperty(String name) {
              return propertiesMap.get(name).toString();
          }
  ```

Comment: thank you, i will try to implement custom PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer!

Comment: I have overrired the function resolvePlaceholder(String placeholder, Properties props, int systemPropertiesMode) in  PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class. That solved my problem. But I do agree with you that initially it would be better to change the way the properties files are initialized but unfortunately it is my client's part of job and i do not have an access to it.